# Apple developer statistic

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

In iTunes Connect and under the download statistics, do downloads done with a redemption code get included in those statistics?

Thank for any answers and sorry for my english!!

Comment: Why the close votes?  It might be an "elementary question", but I do not think this is off topic for [so].

Comment: I suspect because it's not really coding related...off hand, I think they *do* get included, but under a separate purchase code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure they do. Regardless of Free, Paid, or Promo a download of any kind still counts as a "Sale." Education apps downloaded using Edu promo codes are counted. I would assume regular promo's are as well.